# Distinct records with has_many_through rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, distinct, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations, uniq

I have a model "Collection" that has a has_many_through relationship with 3 other models: "Song", "Album" and "Artist", achieved through the join table "Collectionitems" (fwiw collectionitem is polymorphic hence the source option on the has_many declaration in the examples below.)

What I'm trying to accomplish is to ensure that the records put in the join table are uniq (distinct) for the sake for not having an unnecessarily huge table and the obvious not dealing with duplicates.

my first attempt worked in part.

```
has_many :albums, -> { distinct }, through: :collectionitems, source: :collectable, source_type: "Album"
has_many :artists, -> { distinct }, through: :collectionitems, source: :collectable, source_type: "Artist"
has_many :songs, -> { distinct }, through: :collectionitems, source: :collectable, source_type: "Song"
```

This did handle the uniq aspect but if I try to add something that already existed in the colelction an exception was raised.

After some digging I found that I could create a block and override the `<<` operator like so:

```
has_many :albums, -> { distinct }, through: :collectionitems, source: :collectable, source_type: "Album"  do
  def <<(*items)
   super(items) rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
  end
end
has_many :artists, -> { distinct }, through: :collectionitems, source: :collectable, source_type: "Artist" do
  def <<(*items)
    super(items) rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
  end
end
has_many :songs, -> { distinct }, through: :collectionitems, source: :collectable, source_type: "Song" do
  def <<(*items)
    super(items) rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
  end
end
```

This got me one step closer as now the exception was rescued and the record is simple not added if it already exists.

Now the real problem:

Say I have an existing collectionitem row for a song: like so

```
Collection.first << Song.first
```

The song is added properly as it did not already exist in the collection.

Now if I try to add 2 or more songs to that same collection and one of the songs already exists (in this case song 1) the add fails.

```
Collection.first << Song.all
```

The add process begins but since Song 1 already exists an exception is raised and none of the other songs get processed.

What I want is for it to simple skip song one because it's already in the collection. Can someone help me here?